# Retrieve unaligned netlink message size in kernel space

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, netlink

I am working on a Linux kernel module which has a bi-directional communication link with a userspace module provided by netlink.

I have an issue with an incorrect message length calculation on messages sent from userspace to kernel space. The message is sent from userspace like this:

```
this->sendLock.lock();
this->netlinkTxHeader->nlmsg_len = NLMSG_SPACE(len);
this->netlinkTxIov.iov_len = this->netlinkTxHeader->nlmsg_len;

memcpy(NLMSG_DATA(this->netlinkTxHeader), buf, len);

int32_t status = sendmsg(this->netlinkSock, &this->netlinkTxMsg, 0);
```

And is received in kernel space like this:

```
unsigned char* buf = (unsigned char*)NLMSG_DATA(nlh);
int len = NLMSG_PAYLOAD(nlh, 0);
```

However the calculated value of `len` always seems to be the aligned size, which I don't want. For example, I can see from debug information that the userspace process sends a message with a payload of 14 bytes (excluding netlink headers). When this is received in the kernel module, however, `NLMSG_PAYLOAD` returns a length of 16 bytes.

Is there any way to get the unaligned payload length (i.e. the actual payload length) back in the kernel module? I looked through the macros in `netlink.h` but I don't see anything which would help.

Note that the `nlmsghdr` object is derived using the `netlink_rcv_skb()` function in the kernel module.

The only other way I can see to fix this is to prefix the actual length in the payload information which I think would work, but doesn't really feel "correct".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [man 3 netlink](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/netlink.3.html): you need to use `NLMSG_LENGTH(len)` (and not `NLMSG_SPACE(len)`) to calculate the `nlmsg_len` field of the `nlmsghdr`.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the issue straight away. I guess I didn't read the man pages properly!